# using PERFORM to insert a string of SELECT statement into a temp table

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to insert data into a temp_table and then truncating the table after analyzing the result.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validation()
  RETURNS text AS $$
DECLARE counter INTEGER;
DECLARE minsid INTEGER;
DECLARE maxsid INTEGER;
DECLARE rec RECORD;
DECLARE stmt varchar;
BEGIN
  SELECT MIN(sid) INTO minsid FROM staging.validation;
  SELECT MAX(sid) INTO maxsid FROM staging.validation;

  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table (col1 TEXT, col2 INTEGER, col3 BOOLEAN) ON COMMIT DROP;

  FOR counter IN minsid..maxsid LOOP
    RAISE NOTICE 'Counter: %', counter;
    SELECT sql INTO stmt FROM staging.validation WHERE sid = counter;

    RAISE NOTICE 'sql: %', stmt;

    PERFORM 'INSERT INTO temp_table (col1, col2, col3) ' || stmt;

    IF temp_table.col3 = false THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'there is a false value';
    END IF;

  END LOOP;
END; $$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Whenever I run this function
`SELECT * FROM validation();`
I get an error:

`ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "temp_table" Where: PL/pgSQL function validation() line 21 at IF`

Here is how my staging.validation table looks -

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bXO9gqFS-GtcC1qJtgNbFkR6ygOuPtR_RZoU7VNhgrI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What is the value for `stmt` ?? And where is the error? On the  `PERFORM` ?

Comment: `stmt` is a SQL statement, it picks up that value from `staging.validation` table. I think the issue is with IF condition.

Comment: Do you know that the `perform 'something'` is almost same to the `select 'something'`? Probably you want the `EXECUTE` statement instead?

Comment: `RAISE NOTICE 'sql: %', stmt;` gives you the statement without from I suppose - smth like `select col1col2,col3 form temp_table` just before the error - please update post with it

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't have to use DECLARE for every variable, it's enough with one.

```
DECLARE
    counter INTEGER;
    minsid INTEGER;
    maxsid INTEGER;
    rec RECORD;
    stmt varchar;
```

Second, you can't use the temp_table.col3 just like that, you have to query it because it's a table. You could create a variable and query into the table or you could directly make the query.

Variable:

```
-- First you declare de varialbe:
DECLARE
    temp BOOLEAN;

... -- rest of your code

temp := temp_table.col3 FROM temp_table WHERE temp_table.col2=counter;
-- you need something to make the query, here as a test I put col2=counter
IF temp=false THEN
... -- rest of your code
```

Directly:

```
... -- rest of your code
IF (SELECT temp_table.col3 FROM temp_table WHERE temp_table.col2=counter)=false THEN
-- Again, you need something to make the query
... -- rest of your code
```

And third, your function has **RETURNS text**, in your pl the return is missing;

Comment: Good answer, but two notes: `IF temp=false THEN` is ambiguous, `IF temp THEN` should be enough; and the third way: `insert into ... returning * into rec; if rec.col3 then...`.

Comment: Totally rigth  @Abelisto, I didn't notice the RECORD. But since the query is in a PERFORM, the third way also should be in a EXECUTE INTO format.

Comment: @Abelisto can you please elaborate on the third way?

Comment: @Dan thanks for all the pointers, I corrected my code but still stuck with the inner logic, I want to execute the INSERT INTO statement, so that I can fill up my temp_table and can query it whenever there is a 'false' value. And if there is a 'false' value, I want to RETURN col1, col2, and the resultant query that generated output.
Currently, I am using `RAISE NOTICE 'there is a false value';` just as a place holder, and also `RETURNS VOID` as I am not sure what to RETURN.

Comment: If you want to return a row, you can use a `CREATE TYPE test AS (col1 text, col2 integer)` and return it (RETURNS test). Or return a `SETOF record` if you want to return many rows; also you can return a table by using `RETURNS TABLE (col1 text, col2 integer)`. It all depends in what you need.